# C fscanf problem

Tags: c, scanf

If I open a file and use fscanf to read a file like this:

2  41
1  50
1 46
   ....

How do I tell C to read the first number and store it as a variable, then the second as another variable, run a loop, then move on to the next set?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried: fscanf(buildingFile,"%d %d",&type, &stories);  but I don't think it's storing them as different variables.

Comment: @Jesse that sames right, actually.

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't seem to go into the loop. All I get is a blinking cursor.

Comment: I am not having problems with the loop, just how the program reads the file that I opened

Comment: @Jesse: it sounds like what you need is a couple of arrays (or vectors) or else one array (or vector) of a `struct` with two entries, one for the `type` and the other for the `stories` (hopefully, you've gotten that far in your book -- this isn't something you really want to do without an array/vector to store the data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop like this is what you're after:

```
int type, stories;

while (fscanf(buildingFile, "%d %d", &type, &stories) == 2)
{
    printf("Got type=%d, stories=%d\n", type, stories);
    /* Do something with 'type' and 'stories' */
}

if (ferror(buildingFile))
{
    perror("buildingFile");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers about `fscanf`:

1. Always check the return value. If you asked for one integer, it should return `1` if it scanned successfully. Other return values include `0` or `EOF`, which may indicate a failure in reading, or a failure in finding data matching the provided pattern.
2. Whitespace characters are usually ignored unless the format specification includes an `[`, `c` or `n` specifier.
3. Always check the return value.

---

```
while(1)
{
    int result;
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;

    result = fscanf (file, "%d%d", &firstNumber, &secondNumber);
    if (result == 2)
    {
        printf("Scanned two numbers, %d and %d\n", firstNumber, secondNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        if (result != EOF)
            puts("An error occurred");
        break;
    }
}
```